# Django Meta class

Tags: python, django

I'm new to Django. Now I'm learning it with [Writing your first Django app.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial01/)

When I build the following code (from the tutorial) in Sublime Text 2:

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
import datetime

class Poll(models.Model):
    question = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.question


class Choice(models.Model):
    poll = models.ForeignKey(Poll)
    choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.choice_text
```

I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\DjangoProjects\blog\polls\models.py", line 5, in <module>
class Poll(models.Model):
File "C:\python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 93, in __new__
kwargs = {"app_label": model_module.__name__.split('.')[-2]}
IndexError: list index out of range
[Finished in 0.3s with exit code 1]
```

Reading similar questions on *StackOverflow* I have read that I have to add a `Meta class` to each of my classes (*and it helps me*).

**But** in the Django documentation I read the following:

`If a model exists outside of the standard locations (models.py or a models package in an app), the model must define which app it is part of.`

And this is *not my case*.

That's location of the `models.py` in my app:

```
blog/
    manage.py
    blog/
        __init__.py
        settings.py
        urls.py
        wsgi.py
    polls/
        __init__.py
        admin.py
        models.py
        tests.py
        views.py
```

That's what I have in the `settings.py` (if necessary):

```
import os

DEBUG = True
TEMPLATE_DEBUG = DEBUG

ADMINS = (
    # ('Your Name', 'your_email@example.com'),
)

MANAGERS = ADMINS

BASE_DIR = "C:/DjangoProjects/blog"

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3', # Add 'postgresql_psycopg2', 'mysql', 'sqlite3' or 'oracle'.
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),                      # Or path to database file if using sqlite3.
        # The following settings are not used with sqlite3:
        'USER': '',
        'PASSWORD': '',
        'HOST': '',                      # Empty for localhost through domain sockets or '127.0.0.1' for localhost through TCP.
        'PORT': '',                      # Set to empty string for default.
    }
}

# Hosts/domain names that are valid for this site; required if DEBUG is False
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/settings/#allowed-hosts
ALLOWED_HOSTS = []

# Local time zone for this installation. Choices can be found here:
# http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name
# although not all choices may be available on all operating systems.
# In a Windows environment this must be set to your system time zone.
TIME_ZONE = 'Europe/Moscow'

# Language code for this installation. All choices can be found here:
# http://www.i18nguy.com/unicode/language-identifiers.html
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

SITE_ID = 1

# If you set this to False, Django will make some optimizations so as not
# to load the internationalization machinery.
USE_I18N = True

# If you set this to False, Django will not format dates, numbers and
# calendars according to the current locale.
USE_L10N = True

# If you set this to False, Django will not use timezone-aware datetimes.
USE_TZ = True

# Absolute filesystem path to the directory that will hold user-uploaded files.
# Example: "/var/www/example.com/media/"
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'static/')

# URL that handles the media served from MEDIA_ROOT. Make sure to use a
# trailing slash.
# Examples: "http://example.com/media/", "http://media.example.com/"
MEDIA_URL = ''

# Absolute path to the directory static files should be collected to.
# Don't put anything in this directory yourself; store your static files
# in apps' "static/" subdirectories and in STATICFILES_DIRS.
# Example: "/var/www/example.com/static/"
STATIC_ROOT = 'C:/DjangoProjects/blog/static/'

# URL prefix for static files.
# Example: "http://example.com/static/", "http://static.example.com/"
STATIC_URL = '/static/'


# Additional locations of static files
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    # Put strings here, like "/home/html/static" or "C:/www/django/static".
    # Always use forward slashes, even on Windows.
    # Don't forget to use absolute paths, not relative paths.
)

# List of finder classes that know how to find static files in
# various locations.
STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.DefaultStorageFinder',
)

# Make this unique, and don't share it with anybody.
SECRET_KEY = '@iae@w#o=(!9l0qc4jd3wrd&h@po4na7v*a#dq4csvfecy95nv'

# List of callables that know how to import templates from various sources.
TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
    'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
    'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
#     'django.template.loaders.eggs.Loader',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    # Uncomment the next line for simple clickjacking protection:
    # 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'blog.urls'

# Python dotted path to the WSGI application used by Django's runserver.
WSGI_APPLICATION = 'blog.wsgi.application'

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    # Put strings here, like "/home/html/django_templates" or "C:/www/django/templates".
    # Always use forward slashes, even on Windows.
    # Don't forget to use absolute paths, not relative paths.
    "C:/DjangoProjects/blog/templates"
)

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'polls',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable admin documentation:
    # 'django.contrib.admindocs',
)

# A sample logging configuration. The only tangible logging
# performed by this configuration is to send an email to
# the site admins on every HTTP 500 error when DEBUG=False.
# See http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/logging for
# more details on how to customize your logging configuration.
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'filters': {
        'require_debug_false': {
            '()': 'django.utils.log.RequireDebugFalse'
        }
    },
    'handlers': {
        'mail_admins': {
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'filters': ['require_debug_false'],
            'class': 'django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler'
        }
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django.request': {
            'handlers': ['mail_admins'],
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'propagate': True,
        },
    }
}
```

The output of `python manage.py sql polls`:

```
BEGIN;
CREATE TABLE "polls_poll" (
    "id" integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    "question" varchar(200) NOT NULL,
    "pub_date" datetime NOT NULL
)
;
CREATE TABLE "polls_choice" (
    "id" integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    "poll_id" integer NOT NULL REFERENCES "polls_poll" ("id"),
    "choice_text" varchar(200) NOT NULL,
    "votes" integer NOT NULL
)
;

COMMIT;
```

What's can be wrong with this?

Comment: Post the contents of `settings.py`; also, your indenting is off in your code snippet. I hope its indented properly in your actual source.  You should also make sure you have run `python manage.py syncdb`

Comment: @BurhanKhalid Thank you for having called my attention to the identation, I didn't notice it. I added the contents of the `settings.py` file. I hope this will help to understand the situation.

Comment: You have renamed the directory that is being used to `mysite`, where in your `settings.py` everything is pointing to `blog`, is that another typo?

Comment: @BurhanKhalid Oh, sorry. Yes, that was another typo. I fixed it. I apologize for that.

Comment: What is the output of `python manage.py sql polls`?

Comment: @BurhanKhalid, I added the output to the answer.

Comment: I'd like to see how you are importing the models.py in your view and what's in your python path.

Comment: did you define the class meta or not for each model? with that it should works

Comment: @dan-klasson you mean, how I'm importing objects from `models.py` to the `views.py`? Sorry if my questions are annoying :)